# Create different (button) backgrounds using pattern sprite

Tags: jquery, css, css-sprites

I would like to create a web page that has a lot of buttons. Those buttons will have a 'rusty' look on them. To avoid the issue that all the buttons would look exactly the same, I was thinking about creating a sprite png of a pattern and then have each button pick other coordinates of that same sprite.

Is this doable and if so how?
(My guess is that this would involve jquery/javascript probably..)

Simple code on that page (at this moment):

```
<style>
button {
background-image: url("/cssspriteproject/rustpattern2.png");
background-position: -10px -10px;
width:100px;
height:25px;
margin-bottom:3px;
color:#fff;
font-size:10px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<button>test1</button><br>
<button>test2</button><br>
<button>test3</button><br>
<button>test4</button><br>
</body>
```

As you can see, all buttons have the exact same pattern.. I want them to look different from one another.
Right now there are 4 buttons, but I want to use say 100 buttons, so I don't want to use different classes for each one of them.

Comment: I'm hungry for code! Do you have any? -Code Monster

Comment: @Donte'Trumble No, I don't have any yet.. I just would like to know if this is possible at all, and if so how. Just a hint to get me in the right direction...

Comment: Yes, its certainly possible, and not to tricky. make an attempt using a background image from your buttons and update your question when you get stuck

Comment: Yes it is possible.  But, we are here to help/debug your code that you have already started. Here is a good site to help you get started. http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites-workflow/

Comment: Updated my question with some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't repeat just a portion of a background image within an element. You can resize that background image so that only the portion you want to display fills up the background element using `background-size` though.

The other interpretation of what you're asking is that you have a large image of a single pattern (an image much bigger than the element for which it is meant to be the background). Then each button/element shows a different bit of that large pattern. That can be done just by using `background-position` like any other sprite. You just don't have to be as precise on your position.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about your coding style but for me I would first make a sprite including all button backgrounds , then in default use one button with one bg and with an extra class there will be another bg just by changing coordinates of sprite in added class.

```
button{
background: url(../images/sprite.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
button.red{
background: url(../images/sprite.png) no-repeat 0 -100px;
}
button.blue{
background: url(../images/sprite.png) no-repeat -50px -150px;
}
```

Just make a sprite and find the coordinates of your sprite using www.spritecow.com

i hope this works :)

Answer (score 0):

Googled some more and found something similar that didn't use background of any kind, but based on that I got it to work:

```
<style type='text/css'>
button {
background-image: url("/cssspriteproject/rustpattern2.png");
width:100px;
height:25px;
margin-bottom:3px;
color:#fff;
font-size:10px;
}
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.on').each(function() {
     var onpos = (Math.floor(Math.random()*270)) + 'px ' + (Math.floor(Math.random()*270)) + 'px';
     $(this).css('background-position', onpos);
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<button class="on">test1</button><br>
<button class="on">test2</button><br>
<button class="on">test3</button><br>
<button class="on">test4</button><br>

</body>
```

I filled in the approx width and height of my image in the script. Since the image isn't a real pattern, you see a difference in coloring some times, but it works like a charm: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oashcp9d/)